# Java SWT: How to make a button unclickable while a separate thread is running

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have a program in which a `SelectionEvent` listener on a `pushbutton` activates a thread.

During the execution of this thread the button needs to remain grayed out and un-clickable (so as to not run multiples copies of the thread in question), then return to a normal clickable state.

Within the SWT framework, how can I do that?

This is the code I currently have ('ok' is the SWT pushbutton in question):

```
    ok.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
        public void greyOut() {
            ok.setEnabled(false);
        }
        public void ungray() {
            ok.setEnabled(false);
        }           
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {}
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent ef) { 
            ok.setGrayed(true);
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {     
                    greyOut();
                    connectAndDownloadReport();         
                    try {
                        System.setOut(oldOut);
                        ArrayList<Devices> allDevs = parseFile();
                        createCSV(allDevs);

                    }

                    catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        e.getMessage();
                        System.out.close();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    finally {
                        ungray();
                    }

                }           
            });
        }});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `ok.setEnabled(false)` will disable the button, but you must do this is in the UI thread. So in a background thread you would have to use `Display.asyncExec` to run that part of the code:

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() -> ok.setEnabled(false));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you create a class instead of using an anonymous inner class you could pass a reference to the button to the thread and when it finishes it could set it to active again.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know the mechanism to make a button greyed-out. Deleting the listener only makes clicking it useless, but does not make it appear inactive in GUI.

Comment: In this case you have to check the SWT documentation for that option, however, as a workaround, you could add a boolean variable that indicates that the button was already clicked and the thread already created. This way, even if the user clicks again, new threads won't be spawned.

Comment: I unfortunately did not find anything about that in the documentation; closest I could get is how to make a button unfocusable via listener removal. Thanks, I am gonna implement the workaround while continuing to search for a solution