# How to wait for a thread to complete without freezeing SWT GUI?

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

I am trying to make a GUI console with SWT. As such I have two text objects. The first holds everything that would be outputted to the console. The second is editable only when an input method is called. The input method needs to make the second Text object editable (by redefining it as such), allow the user to enter in text into the Text object, and then return that text when the event raised by pressing the enter key occurs. The problem is that the handle event methods cannot return anything. As such they have to set a boolean (inputted) to true, and the program has to wait (e.g. while (!inputted) {continue;}) until text has been entered to return that text. During the waiting process, however, the GUI freezes and the user cannot enter any text. I have tried creating the second Text object in a new thread but that does not fix it. How can I wait for inputted to be true, but allow the user to enter in text while the program is waiting? (I.E. how should this program be multi threaded to allow the GUI to work while it waits for a user-caused event to occur).

Here is the input method in my main program:

```
    public String input(String prompt) {
    inputted=false;
    consoleText+=prompt;
    console.setText(consoleText);
    print("opening");
    Openbox textBoxThread=new Openbox();
    textBoxThread.start();
    Input thread=new Input();
    thread.start();
    
    return returnStr;
}

public void closeTextBox() {
    // box for entering text
    consoleInput = new Text(shell, SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.NONE);
    consoleInput.setBounds(10, 10, 414, 21);
    consoleInput.setText("");
}
```

Here is my Input thread:

```
public class Input extends Thread {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Input thread = new Input();
    thread.start();
    
  }

  public void run(Test test) {
        while(!test.getInputted()) {
            continue;
        }
        test.setReturnStr(test.getConsoleInput().getText());
        test.closeTextBox();
  }
}
```

Here is my OpenBox thread:

```
public class Openbox extends Thread {

    
  private String consoleText;
  private Text consoleInput;
  private Text console;
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Input thread = new Input();
    thread.start();
    
  }

  public void run(Test test) {
        // box for entering text
        consoleInput = test.getConsoleInput();
        consoleText=test.getConsoleText();
        console=test.getConsole();
        consoleInput = new Text(test.getShell(), SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.NONE);
        consoleInput.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_CYAN));
        consoleInput.setBounds(10, 10, 414, 21);
    
        // this following runs the "runs" block when enter is pressed if the textbox is selected
        consoleInput.addListener( SWT.DefaultSelection, new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent( Event event) 
            { // runs 
                consoleText+=consoleInput.getText()+"\n";
                console.setText(consoleText);
            }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is quite hard to follow. You seem to be using more than one thread for UI objects - that isn't allowed, only the single UI thread can access the UI, other threads should be getting errors. Where is your SWT main event loop? Try to show us a [mre]

Comment: Also see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49805758/2670892) for a simple background thread

Comment: I don't know SWT, and I can't give a proper answer, but the GUI thread should _never_ wait for anything. The GUI thread should only react to events. If I was writing it in some other GUI toolkit, I would instantiate a text editor "widget" that reacts to keystrokes by storing text and updating it's on-screen view, and I would register a handler/callback that it would call in reaction to the "enter" key. My callback would get the text of the last line in the buffer, and put it into a blocking queue. Then, some _other_ thread could run procedural code that waits for text to appear in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:
Your GUI needs to be in a separate thread and needs to be the only thread modifying any GUI elements.
Your main thread can then modify boolean values, which are checked by the GUI thread in its main event loop. This allows you to change the GUI without using the main thread.
When waiting on a boolean in the main thread, add a small time delay between checking conditions (not just continue), as otherwise the GUI thread might have problems changing that boolean and ending the main thread's wait.